# How to pass an URL with whitespace in Python 3 urllib.request.urlopen() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

[image: Code Image]

This is the simple program I am trying to run which shows error. If I pass URL without whitespace, then the program runs properly.

Error: 404 Bad Request.

[image: Error]

If instead of "Hey You", I pass "Hey%20You". The program runs correctly.

Comment: It would be better if you don't paste images but instead include the code. Check the formatting FAQ if you want to know how to format code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the string to [urllib.parse.quote](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote) to handle the escaping of special characters such as the space.